# Ocultar etiquetas html al mostrar un elemento con angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Hola estoy usando un editor de texto para guardar datos en una base de datos.

un párrafo se guarda en base de datos así:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Extracto</p>
```

ahora al mostrar este dato en otra pagina después de llamarlo con angular 7, se imprime en pantalla de la misma forma así

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Extracto</p>
```

necesito que al mostrarlo se vea solo el texto "Extracto", sin las etiquetas.

en el html de angular lo muestro asi:

```
<p class="card-title text-center my-1">{{post.extract}}</p>
```

alguna idea de como ocultar las etiquetas Html??.

de ante mano muchas gracias.

Comment: Podrías usar [dom-parse](https://github.com/jacobbuck/dom-parse), que es una librería que te devuelve una lista, que luego puedes usar para extraer el texto que necesitas. No se si le has echado un ojo a eso.

Comment: si es sólo el texto sin formato hay unas pistas aquí -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/47325513/1423096

Comment: @PabloLozano para evitar el [efecto arrastre](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efecto_arrastre) pedir mas detalles al OP antes de marcar como duplicado

Comment: @aloMalbarez si insertas el texto con innerHTML no se ven las etiquetas, ya que pasan a formar parte del documento. Asumí que si guardaban en la base de datos los estilos, era porque esa información era relevante, no usas un editor de texto enriquecido para luego descartar los metadatos

Comment: @PabloLozano una asumpción válida pero estaría bien clarificar concepto e intención de OP donde dice "ocultar etiquetas", y así usar un filtro/pipe o renderizarlo tal cual viene con el property binding. Me da la sensación de que hay espacio para mejorar la pregunta y las respuestas ( la respuesta de esta pregunta y de la enlazada ).

Answer (score 1):

Angular tiene el atributo inner Html para esto. Suponiendo que quieres meter tu texto en un div, quedaría algo como

```
<div [innerHTML]="miStringConHtml" ></div>
```

Ref: [Documentación de Angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-or-interpolation)

Comment: considerar : `necesito que al mostrarlo se vea solo el texto "Extracto", sin las etiquetas.`

Answer (score 0):

Como Pablo Lozano ya te indicó, puedes utilizar `[innerHTML]` para renderizar una cadena que contiene etiquetas HTML dentro de un elemento del DOM.

Si lo que necesitas es, incluso, editar tu cadena que es texto en HTML, te recomiendo utilizar [quill](/questions/tagged/quill), el cual es MUY bueno. Además te permite deshabilitar la edición de código y sólo mostrar tu texto ya formateado.